# Netbeans java unexpected exception

Tags: java

Whenever I try to open or start a new project I get this message "unexpected exception.. could not initialized class sun.awt.shell" what does it mean?
I went to youtube and searched google for help and didn't get any answer, please help

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: What OS? Which Java version? Which version of netbeans? Also `sun.awt.shell` looks like a package name, i.e. the class name seems to be missing, can you post the _entire_ message?

Comment: @YCF_L He can't write any; he can't start a project in his IDE.

Comment: I'm using netbeans 8.2 on windows 10

Comment: Im new here need some reputation to add inage

Comment: _I went to youtube_ This is not really the best search engine ...

Comment: I know youtube isn't the best

Comment: But I had no otherother choice

Comment: what is your version of JDK

Comment: I believe it was 7

Comment: ,I'm reinstalling NetBeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this same issue a few months ago, it is a known bug which was solved in JDK7, Installing the latest version of version of Java worked for me

Check the following link
[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189742)

I hope this helps

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in JDK 7, just update or reinstall the latest version of Java and Netbeans.